# Calculating the Similarity of two raster images: Proper handling of the Alpha Channel?

Tags: image, image-processing, alpha, alpha-transparency

I need to implement a similarity measure for two same sized raster images.

The basic idea is to use one image as the base (average) and substract the other image from the base resulting in an 'error' being the normalized difference between the two corresponding pixel values.

The problem I have is with different alpha values. Appearently the alpha value applies to each color component independently.

One good idea I had was using a background, applying both images to the very same blackground (like random noise, gray, a set of backgrounds (like white and black) and combining the error values for each background... .

Applying each images to the same background before (during) comparison is a pragmatic solution but I would prefer a proofen way to model alpha components and similarity / error correctly.

Comment: Are two fully transparent pixels expected to be equal? If so I'd just use pre-multiplied alpha and ignore the alpha channel altogether.

Comment: I think it is more like alphaA = 0 && alphaB = 0 (or almost 0) makes both values to be weighted 0 and therefor non existance.

Comment: If you do what I suggested then any pixel with alpha=0 will match automatically.